# Excecuting URL two times instead of one time in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-5

I am developing web application using angularJs and Rest Web services. I have written service function for executing web service API and calling from controller.It is working but problem is executing URL two times instead of single time.

Controller

```
invoiceApp.controller('clientController', ['$scope', '$http', 'clientService', function ($scope, $http, clientService) {
        $scope.loadPage = function (url) {
            var request = clientService.list(url);
            request.success(function (data, status) {
                $scope.result = data;
            });
        };
    }]);
```

Service,

```
'use strict';

    invoiceApp.factory('clientService', ['$http', function ($http) {
            var url = 'clients';
            return {
                list: function (newUrl) {
                    url = newUrl ? newUrl : url;
                    return $http.get(url);
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

HTML

```
<table id="dt_basic" class="table table-bordered table-hover" width="100%"  data-ng-init="loadPage()">
.....
...pagination...
  <ul class="pagination pagination-sm pull-right">
                            <li ng-if="result.prev_page_url">
                                <a ng-click="loadPage(result.prev_page_url)" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li ng-if="result.next_page_url">
                                <a ng-click="loadPage(result.next_page_url)" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
</table>
```

Here when I am clicking next page,it works fine but executes URL two times.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should check your `.htaccess` check this [link](http://www.benbybenjacobs.com/blog/2013/05/16/unpredictable-301-permanently-moved-in-embedded-angularjs-built-with-yeoman).

Comment: What is status of "301 Moved Permanently' in one of every two requests?

Comment: Still two urls?? then you should check your `.htaccess` check this [link](http://www.benbybenjacobs.com/blog/2013/05/16/unpredictable-301-permanently-moved-in-embedded-angularjs-built-with-yeoman)

Comment: Yes,when I removed this code `#RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]` from my htaccess file,issue solved.